# Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my app I have a`TabBar`navigation system. When app loads the view controller for the first tab the `calendarTableView` in it loads normally, but if I switch to another tab and then return to the first I get the `NSInternalInconsistencyException Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path` error. Declaring the cell as : `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarTableViewCell` gives me the error. For now, I solved it as advised in other posts by not specifying an indexPath in the cell declaration in `cellForRowAt` method and declaring it as : `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarCell") as! CalendarTableViewCell` but does that mean that I'm managing the data source wrongly or what's the cause of having that error? Shouldn't be `indexPath` always be specified? I did a test as I didn't have the problem until now and I changed the system date to an earlier date say the 10th of the month, and I don't get the error. So does it mean that tableview is trying to dequeue too many cells? Can you see what's happening? I would really appreciate some explanation of this.
As always thank you very much for your time.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarTableViewCell
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarCell") as! CalendarTableViewCell
        cell.configureUi()
        let date = datesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellDate = String( describing: date)
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .weekday], from: date)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        let dayInWeek = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
//        cell.dayLabel.text = "\(String(describing: components.day!))" + " " + "\(dayNamesArray[components.weekday! - 1])"
        cell.dayLabel.text = "\(String(describing: components.day!))" + " " + dayInWeek
        cell.cellWeekday = components.weekday!
        //        print("cell weekday is: \(cell.cellWeekday!)") // prints correct weekday
        cell.cellId = "\(String(format:"%04d", components.year!))" + "\(String(format:"%02d", components.month!))" + "\(String(format:"%02d", components.day!))"
        self.selectedDate = cell.cellId // used for time slots cellId
        //        print("##################### selectedDate in tableview is :\(self.selectedDate) ")
        // highlighting current day cell
        if indexPath.row == self.actualDay - 1 && self.actualMonth == self.displayedMonth {
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
            if Theme.selectedTheme == 1 {
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.calendarCellToday?.cgColor
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.calendarCellTodayRgb.cgColor
                }

            } else if Theme.selectedTheme == 2 {
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.calendarCellToday2?.cgColor
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.calendarCellTodayRgb2.cgColor
                }
            }
            //            print(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   selected cell weekday is: \(cell.cellWeekday!) @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ")
            self.selectedDate = cell.cellId
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CalendarTableViewCell {
            cell.configureUi()
            // highlighting current day cell
            if indexPath.row == self.actualDay - 1 && self.actualMonth == self.displayedMonth {
                cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
                if Theme.selectedTheme == 1 {
                    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                        cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.calendarCellToday?.cgColor
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                        cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.calendarCellTodayRgb.cgColor
                    }
                } else if Theme.selectedTheme == 2 {
                    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                        cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.calendarCellToday2?.cgColor
                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                        cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.calendarCellTodayRgb2.cgColor
                    }
                }
                //            print(" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   selected cell weekday is: \(cell.cellWeekday!) @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ")

                self.selectedDate = cell.cellId
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CalendarTableViewCell {
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
            if Theme.selectedTheme == 1 {
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.firstTintColor?.cgColor
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.firstTintColorRgb.cgColor
                }

            } else if Theme.selectedTheme == 2 {
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

                    cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.firstTintColor2?.cgColor
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    cell.layer.borderColor = Theme.firstTintColorRgb2.cgColor
                }
            }
            self.updateTimeSlots(selectedCell: cell)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let cell: CalendarTableViewCell = tableView(self.calendarTableview, cellForRowAt: IndexPath.init(row: self.actualDay - 1, section: 0)) as! CalendarTableViewCell
        self.updateTimeSlots(selectedCell: cell)

    }
```

Comment: I suspect that the actual reason is in `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation`. You **must not** call the datasource method `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)` yourself. And you are strongly discouraged from manipulating the cells outside of `cellForRow`. Modify the **model** and reload the row.

Comment: @vadian first of all thank you to be always here checking and helping. As for the problem I'm having , indeed it was the problem. I implemented `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` as I declared `self.calendarTableview.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row:self.actualDay - 1,section:0) , at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)` in `viewWillAppear` and I needed to call `self.updateTimeSlots(selectedCell: cell)`when cell creation matched criteria in `if` statement in `cellForRowAt` so I though to call it a scrolling end. I can call it directly within the `if`statement instead.Thanks

Comment: @vadian Maybe you could make your comment to an answer and could be accepted. Then the question could be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the actual reason is in `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation`.

**Never ever** call the datasource method [`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview) (unlike [`cellForRow(at:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow)) yourself. It's exclusively called by the framework.

And you are strongly discouraged from manipulating the cells outside of `cellForRow`. Modify the **model** and reload the row.